# why is the length subtraction returning an error?

Tags: python, subtraction, string-length

For `len(x) - len(y)` below, I seem to be getting an error saying the minus sign(-) is 'an invalid character in identifier'- any idea why?

```
def mxdiflg(a1, a2):
    for x in a1:
        print(len(x))
    for y in a2:
        print(len(y))
        return (max(abs(len(x) − len(y))))

print(mxdiflg(s1,s2))
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What is `s1`? What is `s2`? If you are getting an error post the *full error message* including the stack trace.

Comment: `−` is a long dash, which isn't valid. You need `-`.

Comment: Also, be careful with this algorithm. If `a1` is empty, `x` will never be set, and `len(x)` will cause an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using m-dash instead of <strike>minus sign</strike> hyphen. Replace the line by

```py
return (max(abs(len(x) - len(y))))
```

---

Python as well as most programming languages uses [hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen) "-" for subtraction operation. It can be found to the right of '0' key on most keyboards.

[Em dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Em_dash) "–" is a symbol that is meant to be longer than hyphen, but looks almost the same as hyphen in code because [monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) is commonly used to display the code.

There also exist symbol [minus sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus_and_minus_signs#Minus_sign) "−", but it is not a valid operator in Python. It is commonly used to nicely display negative numbers in user interface, but not in the code.

[Monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) (as seen in the code):

```
"-" hyphen
"–" em dash
"−" minus
```

[Proportional font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeface#Proportion) (regular text):

> "-" hyphen
> "–" em dash
> "−" minus

Comment: Hi sorry if this is ignorant, but your code and mine looks the same? What did you mean by m-dash? The minus sign if the key next to '0' on the keyboard right? Thanks!

Comment: @PatrickChong I've updated the answer and clarified the difference

Answer (score 0):

I think, all your code needs correction.

in `max(abs(len(x) − len(y)))` x carry the final item in the list a1.

Also 'y' in the loop `for y in a2:` will carry only the first item of list a2 then `return (max(abs(len(x) − len(y))))`

***Regrading your first comment***
check the following lines

```
a1=['a','b','c']
for x in a1:
    print(len(x))
print(x)
```

The results

```
1
1
1
c
```

so the final value of `x` is `c`, `so x carry the final item in the list a1`

I wish you got it now, welcome.

Comment: Is that right? Because when I run the following code.    for x in a1: print(Len(x)) it does give me the length of all of the strings in a1? So what did you mean 'x carries the final item in the list a1?'

Comment: I understand and agree with your second point regarding y and the max(...) line though, and I've amended it. So thanks :)